# ipmitool Unable to send command: Invalid argument

Tags: 16.04, ipmi

`ipmitool` is giving me the following `Unable to send command: Invalid argument` what might be the cause of this and how can I solve it

```
user@server:~$ sudo ipmitool sensor | grep Temp
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 85.000    | 90.000    | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 85.000    | 90.000    | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Ambient Temp     | 22.000     | degrees C  | ok    | na        | 3.000     | 8.000     | 42.000    | 47.000    | na
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
CPU Temp Interf  | na         | discrete   | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
Unable to send command: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue by reinstalling `ipmitool`in this sequence

```
sudo apt-get remove ipmitool
sudo reboot
sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get install ipmitool
```